# How to get tableview data with multi button selection swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get data from tableview after clicking save button .But when user second time change the value then, same value two times append .[

> ***`[enter image description here][1]`***

][2]

protocol ButtonSelect {
func tapStar(indexPath: IndexPath, star: Int)
}

class LeaveDayDetailsCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var leaveDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var leaveDateName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var seconButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fullButton: UIButton!

var delegate:ButtonSelect?
var indexpath:IndexPath?




   @IBAction func bittonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    delegate?.tapStar(indexPath: indexpath!, star: sender.tag)
}
```

}

class DayDetailsController: UIViewController{

@IBAction func buttonPresed(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
   // i want to submit tableview result with radio button value change this place
```

// example like

//["03/27/2021 + 1", "03/28/2021 + 2"]

// my result

//["03/27/2021 + 1", "03/28/2021 + 2", "03/27/2021 + 3", "03/28/2021 + 2"]
// same value two  times

```
    }
```

}

extension DayDetailsController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    return listDayDetailsData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"LeaveDayDetailsCell",for: indexPath) as! LeaveDayDetailsCell
    
    cell.leaveDateLabel.text = listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["BreakDate"] as? String ?? "-"
    cell.leaveDateName.text = listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["DateName"] as? String ?? "-"
    
    
    
    
    cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    dayDetailsTableView.rowHeight = 132.00
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.indexpath = indexPath
    return cell
    
}
```

}

extension DayDetailsController:ButtonSelect{

```
func tapStar(indexPath: IndexPath, star: Int) {
    
    let cell = dayDetailsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! LeaveDayDetailsCell
    
    if star == 1{
        
        
        cell.firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioFull.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.seconButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.fullButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        
        
        totalvalue = star
        
    }
    
    else if star == 2{
        
        cell.firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.seconButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioFull.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.fullButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        
        
        totalvalue = star
        
        
        
    }
    
    else  if star == 3{
        
        
        
        cell.firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.seconButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioBlank.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.fullButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioFull.png"), for: .normal)
        
        
        totalvalue = star
        
        
    }
    
   
    
  
    

    answerValue.append("\(listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["BreakDate"] as! String) + \(totalvalue)")
    
    print(answerValue,"****answer")
   
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Keep the **star** count in your **listDayDetailsData** and update the value according to the button taps

**LeaveDayDetailsCell**

```
class LeaveDayDetailsCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var leaveDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var leaveDateName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var seconButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fullButton: UIButton!

}
```

**DayDetailsController extension**

```
extension DayDetailsController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return listDayDetailsData.count
}

@objc func firstButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let index = sender.tag
    // Update star value in listDayDetailsData[index]
    
    // Reload single row at index 0
    dayDetailsTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
}
@objc func secondButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let index = sender.tag
    // Update star value in listDayDetailsData[index]
    
    // Reload single row at index 0
    dayDetailsTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
}
@objc func fullButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let index = sender.tag
    // Update star value in listDayDetailsData[index]
    
    // Reload single row at index 0
    dayDetailsTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"LeaveDayDetailsCell",for: indexPath) as! LeaveDayDetailsCell
    
//    cell.leaveDateLabel.text = listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["BreakDate"] as? String ?? "-"
//    cell.leaveDateName.text = listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["DateName"] as? String ?? "-"
    
    cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.firstButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.seconButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.fullButton.tag = indexPath.row
    
    cell.firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(firstButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(secondButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fullButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    switch listDayDetailsData[indexPath.row]["Star"] as! Int {
    case 1:
        // Update your cell buttons
        break
    case 2:
        // Update your cell buttons
        break
    case 3:
        // Update your cell buttons
        break
    default:
        // Default case
        break
    }
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 132.00
}
}
```

**Pro tip:**

It's better to use an Object for keeping your data than a Dictionary

eg

```
struct DayDetails {

var breakDate: String

var dateName: String

var stars: Int

//....

}
```

And there are third party libraries available for handling star rating UI as well
https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos